# How do you make the area of hover in css larger

Tags: css, menu, hover, size, area

I have a list in html that I am formatting as a drop down menu in CSS, however, when I hover over, only the first half of the text is responding, as opposed to the entire length of it, and I can't figure out which property to change in order to make this hover area longer.

thanks!

code:

```
#navbar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: -27px;
    /*height: 13px; */
    float: left;
}

#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left; 
}

#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: #00AA63;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

#navbar li ul {
    color: #fff;
    display: none; 
    width: 10em;
}

#navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    /*width: 200%;*/
}

#navbar li:hover li {
    float: none; 
    /*width: 200%;*/
}

#navbar li:hover li a {
    background-color: #00AA63;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff; 
}

#navbar li li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #33BB96; 
}
```

Jquery stuff:

```
document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML += '<ul id="navbar">'
    + '<li><a href="#">other electives</a>'
    +   '<ul id="navbar">'
    +       '<li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>'
    +       '<li><a href="#">Second Subitem</a></li>'
    +       '<li><a href="#">Numero Tres</a></li></ul>'
    + '</li>'
```

edit:
implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/CLVwv/1/

Comment: Please share your code, or better yet, make a http://jsfiddle.net/ to replicate your problem.

Comment: sorry, first time asking a question on here, the code is here now!

Comment: I would probably try to wrap the element in a div and give the div the onhover attribute.

Comment: what do you want other than this http://jsfiddle.net/tReeM/

Comment: yeah, that's the weird part I suppose, when you just have 1 it's working, but when you stick more behind eachother the hover area halves, but that's exactly what I want ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CLVwv/1/ that's a really nice tool! not sure if this works, but I eddited to be the way I have it, an now you'll see the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because you have set negative margin on each `ul`.

Just remove the padding from `.navbar` and reduce the margin to get the spacing you desire.

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 1px;
    /*height: 13px; */
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

You can also reduce your CSS by removing the ID tags and using a `.navbar` class, this will also make your code more flexible as you don't have to add any new CSS each time you wish to add an item to the menu:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 1px;
    /*height: 13px; */
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: #00AA63;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.navbar li ul {
    color: #fff;
    display: none; 
    width: 10em;

}

.navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    /*width: 200%;*/
}

.navbar li:hover li {
    float: none; 
    /*width: 200%;*/
}

.navbar li:hover li a {
    background-color: #00AA63;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff; 
}

.navbar li li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #33BB96; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">other electives</a>
       <ul class="navbar">
           <li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Second Subitem</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Numero Tres</a></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">other electivesother electives</a>
       <ul class="navbar">
           <li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Second Subitem</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Numero Tres</a></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">other electives</a>
       <ul class="navbar">
           <li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Second Subitem</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Numero Tres</a></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/georeith/CLVwv/2/ for a working solution.

Comment: thank you! that is awesome! Will mess around with these answers and I think I should be able to fix it now :D thanks a lot, this site is awesome!

Comment: @TheLaurens No problem. Be careful using the accepted answers code as it reuses the same ID multiple times and is invalid HTML. Make sure to convert them to classes.

Comment: I will! I have some more code around it, so copy pasting is not going to work anyway! (thank you for the headsup though, might have caused me some trouble)

Answer (score 3):

The reason that's happening is because of the negative margins you have on the ul's. ul#navbar2 is covering #navbar1 and #navbar3 is covering #navbar2.

Is there a reason you need three seperate ul's?  If you use the following html the issue is resolved:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">other electives</a>
       <ul class="navbar">
           <li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Second Subitem</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Numero Tres</a></li></ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">other electivesother electives</a>
       <ul class="navbar">
           <li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Second Subitem</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Numero Tres</a></li></ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">other electives</a>
       <ul class="navbar">
           <li><a href="#">Subitem One</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Second Subitem</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Numero Tres</a></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I also added a 3px padding to #navbar li:

```
#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left; 
    padding-right: 3px;
}
```

See the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/2wFjA/1/

Comment: the fiddle isn't working ;) but I think I get what you mean, and I don't know, I suppose one ul would be enough? I just wanted more of what I had, so I copied it, haven't coded a lot of web things yet ;)

Comment: oops. I had the wrong fiddle url.  I forked yours. I edited with the new one.

Comment: This is invalid HTML, you have used the same ID tag multiple times. Use classes instead.

Comment: George, your right.  I just removed the the extra ul's and didn't really pay attention to the rest.  Fixed it now.  Thanks George.